# Почему со временем функция начинает медленее выполняться

Tags: python, python-2.7

Есть функция которая по заданным координатам водит мышкой, но спустя время, время на выполнение функции растет

Пробовал использовать библиотеку `pyautogui` модуль `moveTo` тот же результат

p.s. python 2.7, windows 7

```
import keyboard
import time
import gc

from external_modules.AutoHotPy.AutoHotPy import AutoHotPy

auto = AutoHotPy()
        
def area_screenshot(coordinates):
    for coord in coordinates:
        x_cur, y_cur = coord[0], coord[1]
        auto.sendToDefaultMouse(x_cur, y_cur)

coordinates = [[123,456],[1135,575],[1000,546],[456,900],[900,241],[234,64],[234,352],
               [123,456],[1135,575],[1000,546],[456,900],[900,241],[234,64],[234,352],
               [123,456],[1135,575],[1000,546],[456,900],[900,241],[234,64],[234,352]]

while 1:
    start = time.clock()
    area_screenshot(coordinates)
    print('area_screenshot: {}'.format((time.clock() - start)))
    
    if keyboard.is_pressed('0'):
        break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если вместо экрана писать в файл? ;)  Скорее всего у вас тормозит вывод на терминал, когда там много уже инфы.

Comment: поменял код, ситуация не изменилась

Comment: Странно. Ну тогда не знаю, что это может быть.

Comment: а попрбуйте такой код на последней версии питона, возможно это старый баг кторый уже исправили ?

Comment: Запустите программу включив профилирование цикла в начале исполнения и после некоторой задержки (когда уже видно торможение), и сравните.

Comment: а сколько лет надо ждать? и что там за external_modules? я хочу воспроизвести ситуацию

Comment: А нет возможности на актуальной версии питона проверить? Хотя бы не на 2.х, а на 3.х каком-то.

Comment: я бы посмотрел что там гбшник скажет раз уж подключен, возможно его периодически стоит принуждать к исполнению

Comment: @Интик Попробовал тот же код на python 3.8 32bit (так как модуль AutoHotPy работает только с 32 битной версией), результат не изменился

Comment: @Daniil Loban Прошу прощения, что такое гбшник?

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко  `gc` он же GarBage collection =) с помощью него можно перидически вручную подчищать мусор

Comment: Если  запустить на пару часов, от какой результат получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно говоря со стороны питона проблем нет: есть вызов модуля, который вызывает функцию из dll (self.interceptionDll)
Почему не попробовать модуль pynput